# Trouble figuring out these tough Big-O examples

Tags: algorithm, loops, big-o

I'm trying to study for an upcoming quiz about Big-O notation.  I've got a few examples here but they're giving me trouble.  They seem a little too advanced for a lot of the basic examples you find online to help.  Here are the problems I'm stuck on.

```
1.     `for (i = 1; i <= n/2; i = i * 2) {
            sum = sum + product;
            for (j= 1; j < i*i*i; j = j + 2) {
                sum++;
                product += sum;
            }
       }`
```

For this one, the `i = i * 2` in the outer loop implies O(log(n)), and I don't think the `i <= n/2` condition changes anything because of how we ignore constants.  So the outer loop stays O(log(n)).  The inner loops condition `j < i*i*i` confuses me because its in terms of 'i' and not 'n'.  Would the Big-O of this inner loop then be O(i^3)?  And thus the Big-O for the entire problem 
be O( (i^3) * log(n) )?

```
2.      `for (i = n; i >= 1; i = i /2) {
             sum = sum + product
             for (j = 1; j < i*i; j = j + 2) {
                 sum ++;
                     for (k = 1 ; k < i*i*j; k++)
                     product *= i * j;
             }
        }`
```

For this one, the outermost loop implies O(log(n)).  The middle loop implies, again unsure, O(i^2)?  And the innermost loop implies O(i^2*j)?  I've never seen examples like this before so I'm almost guessing at this point.  Would the Big-O notation for this problem be O(i^4 * n * j)?

```
3.     `for (i = 1; i < n*n; i = i*2) {
            for (j = 0; j < i*i; j++) { 
                sum ++;
                for (k = i*j; k > 0; k = k - 2)
                    product *= i * j;
            }
       }`
```

The outermost loop for this one has an n^2 condition, but also a logarithmic increment, so I think that cancels out to be just regular O(n).  The middle loop is O(i^2), and the innermost loop is I think just O(n) and trying to trick you. So for this problem the Big-O notation would be O(n^2 * i^2)?

```
4.     `int i = 1, j = 2;
            while (i <= n) {
                sum += 1;
                i = i * j;
                j = j * 2;
       }`

For this one I did a few iterations to better see what was happening:
i = 1,    j = 2
i = 2,    j = 4
i = 8,    j = 8
i = 64,   j = 16
i = 1024, j = 32
```

So clearly, 'i' grows very quickly, and thus the condition is met very quickly.  However I'm not sure just what kind of Big-O notation this is.

Any pointers or hints you can give are greatly appreciated, thanks guys.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out asymptotic bounds for the running time or for `sum`?

Comment: No, I'm trying to estimate the Upper-bound of the run-time for the code fragments as a whole.

Comment: I was going to attempt to answer your question but it seems like your prof is really good. Here is a good paper that you may find useful: http://web.mit.edu/16.070/www/lecture/big_o.pdf

Comment: Thanks, this clears up some of my main questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add i or j to O-notation, it must be converted to n.

For the first one:

Let k be log 2 i.

Then inner loop is done 2^(k*3)/2=2^(3k-1) times for each iteration of outer loop.

k goes from 1 to log2n. 
So total number of iterations is 
sum of 2^(3k-1) for k from 1 to log 2 n which is 4/7(n^3-1) according to Wolfram Alpha, which is O(n^3).

For the last one, i=j1*j2*j3*...jk,  and jm=2^m

i=2^1*2^2*...2^k=2^(1+2+...k)

So 1+2+3+...+k=log 2 n

(k+1)k/2 = log 2 n

Which is O(sqrt(log n))

BTW, log n^2 is not n. 
This question is better to ask at computer science than here.